# Dynamically create a new type in python

Tags: python, c++, rtti

I am writing C++ plugins that exposes 'properties' that may be of various types. In short, a property in this context is a variable, together with some metadata. The properties are mainly holding values of simple types like, ints, doubles etc, but can also be user defined types/structures.

In C++, clients of the plugins can get a pointer to a property, and then manipulate it.

From python, on the other hand, simple wrapper functions can return a handle to a propertys value, e.g.

```
aValue = ctypes.c_double()
getPropertyValue(handleToAProperty, ctypes.byref(aValue))
```

which works fine for POD's.

But how to deal with a user defined type?

E.g. if a user defined type is:

```
class myType
{
private:
    double a;
public:
    void setA(double a);
    double getA();
}
```

Is there any way to *dynamically* create something(??) on the client side that allows the client to retrieve and set the value of the  member variable 'a' in the class above?

I could write a simple wrapper class, I assume but would be happy if one could get around that.

Comment: what is the duty of python here? do you mean you want to use python to operate with C++ class? or you will use C++ to operate python class?

Comment: watch the word dynamically! No boost here..

Comment: I am afraid you are out of luck - :-(

Answer (score 1):

The class information, and not even the public methods information, is automatically included in a dynamically compiled C or C++ file.

The C/C++ compilers know how to validate the public functions in a compiled file, and even do parameter/return value type checking, because they verify this information at *compile* time  in the C header files.

Even the Boost wrapper builders have to import the C/C++ header files and are able to access class members, etc... due to information fetched at compile time.

So, it can be possible to be able to findout C/C++ data structures and method signatures dynamically in a running Python program: but you have to keep in mind that ordinarily this information is not even in the library files. So, any approach you try will have to be able to scan the headerclass definition c++ files at program runtime, so that it can perform the needed introspection.

Knowing that, now, you have to search about C++/C header files parsing modules for Python, and check if any of them suit your needs - this home page of one such projects do list other similar projects in the introductory documentation, so you may find one that suits you:

https://github.com/albertz/PyCParser (note , though, that only C is supported).

Another technology that automatically exposes C classes (sic - it is an OO framework to pure C) to be used in other languages, Python included, is gobject/gobject introspection. It should work fine with Python3, but I don't have any idea if it a) works with C++ classes, b) allow the introspection without you having to modify your classes to use gobject stuff itself.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I am probably reverting to good old wrapping :)

Answer (score 0):

a libray in BOOST call Boost.Python has boost::python::object::ptr, which returns a PyObject* -- so that Python can operate c++ class, is this what you want?

Comment: Nope. I believe that works if I already have wrapped the C++ code, by swig for example. In essence what I want todo is to create the PyObject object, on the fly. Sounds wild, and I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: may i understand as this: if there is helper to wrapper c++ objec to pyobject, you want this helper be created dynamically?